What is the Integral of a Product of a Logistic Function and a Log-Normal Density Function?
I am trying to find the following integral:
$$\alpha = \int_{0}^{\infty} P(y)z(y) dy$$
$P(y)$ is a standard logistic function which approaches 1 for $y \to\infty$. $z(y)$ is a standard log-normal distribution.
In the following graph the green curve is the function $A = P(y)z(y)$, the red one is $z(y)$ and the blue one is $P(y)$. The area under A is clearly positive.

My approach was to use integration by parts. The general formula for this is:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} u v' \, dy = \left. uv \right|_{0}^{\infty} - \int_{0}^{\infty} u' v \, dy$$
I set the following for u, u', v and v':
$$
\begin{align*}
u &= P(y) = \frac{1}{1 + \exp(-8 a (-b + y))} \\[10pt]
v' &= z(y) = \frac{\sqrt{2} \exp\left(-\frac{(\ln(y) - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)}{2 y \sigma \sqrt{\pi}} \\[10pt]
v &= -\frac{1}{2} \, \text{erf}\left(-\frac{\sqrt{2} \ln(y)}{2\sigma} + \frac{\mu \sqrt{2}}{2\sigma}\right) \\[10pt]
u' &= \frac{dP(y)}{dy} = \frac{8 a \exp(-8 a (-b + y))}{\left(1 + \exp(-8 a (-b + y))\right)^2}
\end{align*}$$
Using:
$$
\begin{align*}
P(0) &\in [0,1] \\
P(\infty) &= 1 \\
v(0) &= -1/2 \\
v(\infty) &= 1/2 \\
\end{align*}$$
It seems that this does not help though:
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} P(y)z(y) \, dy = \left. P(y) v \right|_{0}^{\infty} - \int_{0}^{\infty} u' v \, dy
\end{align*} \\
= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{P(0)}{2} - \int_{0}^{\infty} 
\frac{8 a \exp(-8 a (-b + y))}{\left(1 + \exp(-8 a (-b + y))\right)^2}
-\frac{1}{2} \, \text{erf}\left(-\frac{\sqrt{2} \ln(y)}{2\sigma} + \frac{\mu \sqrt{2}}{2\sigma}\right) dy
$$
The new integral is not easier to solve than the original one.
Which other approach could I try?

Hint: $v=1$ is wrong. Take its derivative and compare it with your $v',.$

Thanks for pointing out the obvious! You are of course right @KurtG. I had in mind that the integral of v' from 0 to infinity is 1, which blocked me to see my error.  Unfortunately, I haven't yet found a way to solve the integral. I updated the question.
